# Zend_Form setLabel not working with norwegian characters

Tags: forms, zend-framework

I'm using Zend_Form to create forms and I have an issue with the setLabel-function. I want to set the label using a variable: $value. The problem is that the $value (which is a string) contains some characters from the Norwegian alphabet (æøå). Because of the these characters the label shows as empty. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Example php code:

```
...
$checkbox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('someid');
$checkbox ->setLabel($value);  //$value has value 'Håvard'.
...
```

Html output:

```
<dt id="someid-label"><label for="someid" class="optional"></label></dt>
<dd id="someid-element">
<input type="hidden" name="someid" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="someid" id="someid" value="1"></dd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error in your application encoding. Please set anywhere UTF-8. I have tested with `$value = 'Håvard'` and form renders with correct label.

Comment: I have tried some different encodings without luck. What do you mean by: "Please set anywhere UTF-8"?

Comment: I like to set up UTF-8 charset for DB and site. And setLabel() works fine for UTF8.